# Late 80s sci-fi movie scene: woman morphs into machine/battle station

Tags: story-identification, movie

This may be a long shot, because I only hazily remember one scene that I saw as a kid on the screens in a costco warehouse store. Must have been very late 80s or very early 90s. The scene:

Woman (or smooth-skinned male??) Kneeling down on the ground, face in her hands. Surrounded by troops, I think, inside a large warehouse/factory or something. When she looks up, her face has become all cracked/fragmented/metallic, and she starts "unfolding" (transforming) out into some big battle station like machine, and exchanges hostile fire while still continuing to morph.

...then I don't know, mom called me away! Always wondered what that one was.

Comment: I don't think it actually matches, but there is Tetsuo, 1989 http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096251/

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't sound like it would be it... this was more--I don't know--futuristic... like some kind of alien intelligence android, or cyborg from the future or something. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Superman 3, perhaps? At the end a woman gets turned into a robot or something. It used to really freak me out when I was small.

Comment: +1 for remembering MJ as a woman.

Answer (score 16):

I"m very confident that it is Michael Jackson's [Moonwalker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonwalker). He transforms into a car near the start of the movie then a battle station and a spaceship the end.

Here is the scene:

Comment: Spot on. Can't believe it took a year for this to get answered - the description is very detailed and accurate, with the minor exception of "Woman (or smooth-skinned male??)"!

Comment: it was woman (or smooth-skinned male??) that led me to micheal jackson!

Comment: You never see Michael Jackson and Diana Ross in the same place.

Comment: YES you've nailed it!!  =D  (...And, is that the guy from Home Alone?) I don't think I even knew who Michael Jackson was at the time (when I would have seen this as a "sheltered" 9 or 10 y/o...) That's hilarious to me that I remembered MJ as a woman all these years!  Mystery solved--better late than never. Thanks!

Comment: yeah joe pesci and sean lennon is one of the kids

Comment: “I don't think I even knew who Michael Jackson was at the time (when I would have seen this as a "sheltered" 9 or 10 y/o...)” — given what came out since, that was probably for the best.

Comment: Good find @howler. Looking back, that is some pretty creepy stuff.